# How to draw pie-chart visualization in kibana with the data of sub-string values of a similar records as explained below?

Tags: logstash, kibana, kibana-5, kibana-6

kibana has filtered out the following data records as shown below

> message:"I wish to go to"

**Filter Results:**

```
message:I wish to go to India
message:I wish to go to Australia
message:I wish to go to China
message:I wish to go to Japan
message:I wish to go to India
message:I wish to go to Australia
message:I wish to go to India
message:I wish to go to Australia
message:I wish to go to India
message:I wish to go to India
message:I wish to go to Australia
```

I need to draw a visualization pie-chart with the count of sub-string data in * here

```
( I wish to go to *)
```

I need the visualization like this:

[image]

How to do this?

Comment: I need the visualization of counts of the values ( marked as * above). Also, I wanted the chart dynamically change as the new data arrives with different values.

Answer (score 0):

Create a scripted field, (say) destination, in kibana with script like "params['_source']['message'].substring(13)"

In the pie-chart visualization, use "Count" as Metric and split the slices on "destination".